# How should I structure my Python module so that I can run older versions at any time in the future?

Tags: python, git

I have a Python module which generates forecasts for a specific area of our business. The module contains not only my forecasts, but also those of others which act as inputs into my forecasts, or use my forecast as an input.

We make many changes over time to the code in the repository. I would like to be able to run the code as of some date in the past at all times. Ideally, I would be able to name versions or releases and specifically run that file. As of right now, the only way I could imagine doing this is by having a bunch of if statements in my code. That can't be best practice though, hence me asking here.

I recognize that I will also need to store data inputs as of the date of the run - I'm able to handle that myself. What I am specifically asking about is how to store versions of the code base so that they can be easily run - ideally in parallel on an EC2 cluster.

Repo structure:

```
parent-folder
- Dockerfile
- forecasting-code
    - requirements.txt
    - forecast_runner.py
    - config.py
    - module
        - forecasts
            - volume_forecast.py
            - conversion_forecast.py
            - profitability_forecast.py
        - models
            - price_elasticity.py
        - scripts
            - load_data.py
    - data_inputs
        - sql
        - csv
        - pkl
    - auth_files
        - google_sheets
        - db
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need version control. And maybe something like Docker, if you want.

Comment: This is all backed up in git. What I'm specifically asking about is how I can run a specific prior commit in the command line in parallel with the current version so that I can compare the outputs directly

Comment: ...check the old version out to another directory? I'm not sure that I understand the question.

Comment: An Airflow job runs this forecast code daily based on what is in the repo. just so I'm sure I understand your proposal properly, you're suggesting creating separate folders for each forecast version we want to run on the server, and running separate Airflow jobs within each repo?

Comment: I guess "Airflow" is this Python module you're describing? What's wrong with checking another version out to another directory?

Comment: Sorry no, Airflow is referring to Apache Airflow, the workflow scheduler https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with checking out an old copy and running it in a separate Airflow job?

Comment: Nothing! Like I said, I wanted to confirm my understanding of your proposal. That might work, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help you is tagging your commits for each release. That way you have an easy way to see which commits are real released vs small changes in between which may or may not work.

One workflow is to use pip.
You can use pip to install from git.

```
pip install git+https://myrep.com/mypath@1.0
```

Alternately, you could install from the path as editable.

```
pip install -e .
```

That way, everytime you checkout a new tag you don't need to reinstall.